# Why XPATH with SAML prefix can get SAML2 prefix element?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, saml, saml-2.0

I am implementing saml app using .NET core. I have question about

```cs
SelectSingleNode(string xpath, XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr)
```

My SAMLResponse have saml2 and saml2p prefix.

For example

```xml
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">

<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
```

There is method call

```cs
_xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion", GetNamespaceManager())
```

where _xmlDoc is SAMLResponse that have saml2 and saml2p prefix and GetNamespaceManager() is

```cs
private XmlNamespaceManager GetNamespaceManager()
{
    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(_xmlDoc.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
    manager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
    manager.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");

    return manager;
}
```

Why that method call can return SAML2 prefix element even the XPATH selector is saml/samlp prefix?? I am very confused about this.

p.s. I use library from https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml for developing my saml app.

[Update 14:21 30 Sep 2019 GMT+7] I try out changing prefix in both `SelectSingleNode` and `XmlNamespaceManager` to some prefix that is not saml or saml2. The result from changing is same. I think there is something about xml prefix and namespace. I need some extra explanation.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a very good already I just have some pointers: Please refrain from adding Tags to a question title, except for if those tags come up naturally in the question. Also, please a code identifier to your code fences, like so: `\`\`\`[code identifier]`. Many Languages are supported out of the box like `c#`, `xml`, `xaml` and the list goes on

Answer (score 0):

> Why that method call can return SAML2 prefix element even the XPATH selector is saml/samlp prefix?

You have added those namespace prefixes to the namespace manager, using the same actual namespace declaration used in the XML itself for the `saml2p` and `saml2` prefixes. I.e. you have told the namespace manager that the `samlp` prefix should correspond to the XML namespace `"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"`, which is the same namespace that the `saml2p` prefix corresponds to.

The XPATH selector using your `samlp` prefix will match *any* namespace prefix that is declared to correspond go the `"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"` namespace. Since the `saml2p` prefix does, it will match the node with that prefix.

Likewise for `saml2` and `saml`.

It is very important to make sure you are not conflating the XML namespace prefix with the XML namespace itself. The namespaces in your XML are the strings `"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"` and `"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"`. The prefixes are the identifiers `saml2p`, `saml2`, `samlp`, and `saml` (and `ds`, for that matter). The prefixes are just ways of referring to the actual namespaces.

So, in the same way that two different variables can be assigned to the same string value, and thus those two different variable names can "mean" the same string value in the code, so too do the two XML namespace prefixes `saml2p` and `samlp` mean the same thing, as do `saml2` and `saml`.

So for the purposes of naming XML nodes, whether via XPATH or any other search mechanism in the API, the thing that matters is the *namespace* itself, not whatever prefix was used to specify the namespace.

Thus, your XPATH expression `"/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion"` can find the `Assertion` element in your XML, even though that expression uses different prefixes than those used in the XML document itself. The node references in the XPATH are still in the same namespace as declared in the XML itself.